# Team Explorer Everywhere: Could not execute HistoryAction. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, tfs, version-control, team-explorer-everywhere

I am having and error every time I try to execute "View History" option from any branch and file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA5Jc.png

"Could not execute HistoryAction"

I tried to reinstall TEE and Eclipse, deleting plugin cache, changing default timeout in eclipse.ini config file, re-mapping and creating workspace... but any of that actions works.

This is the log:

```
2019-01-15 13:25:00,024 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.telemetry.TfsTelemetryHelper) Plugin for Eclipse v.14.134.0.201804261732
2019-01-15 13:25:00,024 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.telemetry.TfsTelemetryHelper) AppInsights telemetry initialized
2019-01-15 13:25:00,024 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.telemetry.TfsTelemetryHelper)     Developer Mode: false
2019-01-15 13:25:00,024 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.telemetry.TfsTelemetryHelper)     Production Environment: true
2019-01-15 13:25:00,334 INFO  [Worker-2: Connecting to Team Foundation Server] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.project.ProjectRepositoryManager) Starting TFS repository manager
2019-01-15 13:25:00,433 INFO  [Worker-3: Connecting to Server] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.autoconnect.UIAutoConnector) Auto connecting to the previously used server: https://myClientTfsUrl.com/tfs
2019-01-15 13:25:01,526 INFO  [Worker-3: Connecting to Server] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.ConnectToDefaultRepositoryCommand) Connecting to server
2019-01-15 13:25:01,636 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.ConnectToConfigurationServerCommand) Connecting to server
2019-01-15 13:25:01,638 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.ConnectToConfigurationServerCommand) Connecting to https://myClientTfsUrl.com/tfs as myTfsUser
2019-01-15 13:25:01,691 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory) HttpClient configured for https://myClientTfsUrl.com/tfs, authenticating as myTfsUser
2019-01-15 13:25:02,036 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded native_auth with System.loadLibrary()
2019-01-15 13:25:02,038 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Loaded GSSAPI library: libgssapi_krb5.dylib
2019-01-15 13:25:02,054 WARN  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Could not get principal for kerberos 5 credentials (No credentials cache file found)
2019-01-15 13:25:02,055 WARN  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Could not get principal for kerberos 5 credentials (No credentials cache file found)
2019-01-15 13:25:02,290 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.GetDefaultProjectCollectionCommand) Opening default Team Project Collection
2019-01-15 13:25:02,342 INFO  [Build Status Manager] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.server.cache.buildstatus.BuildStatusManager$BuildStatusManagerRefreshWorker) Starting build status refresh worker
2019-01-15 13:25:02,392 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.GetDefaultWorkspaceCommand) Opening workspace for myTfsUrl.com
2019-01-15 13:25:03,170 INFO  [CancellableCommandThread-41] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded native_filesystem with System.loadLibrary()
2019-01-15 13:25:03,194 INFO  [Worker-6: Querying Team Projects] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamProjectsCommand) Querying Team Projects
2019-01-15 13:25:03,195 INFO  [Worker-0: Querying Team Projects] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamProjectsCommand) Querying Team Projects
2019-01-15 13:25:03,196 INFO  [Worker-4: Querying Team Projects] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamProjectsCommand) Querying Team Projects
2019-01-15 13:25:03,362 INFO  [Worker-6: Querying Team Projects] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.configuration.internal.TFSEntitySessionFactory) Creating catalog-based configuration entity session for https://myClientTfsUrl.com/tfs/something/
2019-01-15 13:25:03,792 INFO  [Worker-7: Querying Teams] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamsCommand) Querying Teams
2019-01-15 13:25:07,960 INFO  [Worker-8: Querying Teams] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamsCommand) Querying Teams
2019-01-15 13:25:08,060 INFO  [Worker-11: Querying Teams] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.commands.QueryTeamsCommand) Querying Teams
2019-01-15 13:25:09,719 INFO  [Worker-4: Initializing TFVC Source Control Explorer] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.VersionControlEditor$VersionControlEditorInitializeCommand) Initializing TFVC Source Control Explorer
2019-01-15 13:25:22,096 ERROR [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.HistoryAction) Error running HistoryAction
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.tasks.vc.ViewHistoryTask.run(ViewHistoryTask.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.HistoryAction.doRun(HistoryAction.java:40)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.framework.action.ExtendedAction.run(ExtendedAction.java:58)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.TeamViewerAction.runWithEvent(TeamViewerAction.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4319)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
2019-01-15 13:25:38,437 ERROR [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.HistoryAction) Error running HistoryAction
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.tasks.vc.ViewHistoryTask.run(ViewHistoryTask.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.HistoryAction.doRun(HistoryAction.java:40)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.framework.action.ExtendedAction.run(ExtendedAction.java:58)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.actions.TeamViewerAction.runWithEvent(TeamViewerAction.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4319)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Microsoft `com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.tasks.vc.ViewHistoryTask` class. Probably only Microsoft can tell you anything about this.

Comment: My coworker can do this action with his Mac without errors so I do not think the problem lies in com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.tasks.vc.ViewHistoryTask

Comment: Is your coworker using an earlier version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd need to see your `platform.log` to know for sure, but I suspect that you're also running into [bug 290](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/290) which results from a deprecated SWT widget being removed.  The underlying cause is that the [`HistoryTreeControl`](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/1c00be8bdc472bed88562cc6be08015d4e1a710c/source/com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui/src/com/microsoft/tfs/client/common/ui/controls/vc/history/HistoryTreeControl.java) uses a [`TableTreeViewer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/1c00be8bdc472bed88562cc6be08015d4e1a710c/source/com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui/src/com/microsoft/tfs/client/common/ui/controls/vc/history/HistoryTreeControl.java#L425) which was deprecated and ultimately [removed in Eclipse 4.10](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fporting%2Fremovals.html&resultof=%22tabletreeviewer%22%20%22tabletreeview%22%20).

Regrettably, at the moment, I would encourage you to either downgrade your Eclipse, vote on [that issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/290), view history on the web or some combination of those options.

Comment: I've downgraded Eclipse from version 4.10.0 to 4.7.2 and now Team Explorer Everywhere it's working correctly. Thanks a lot!!!